# not getting the right results when I update table from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to use update / where  in a sql query to match ID's and then pull the data associated into my table.

I am running into a  problem.

First, when I run

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.column = table2.column
FROM table2
WHERE table1.columnB = table2.columnB
```

it works on some and not others. its like 50/50 success. Some of the results are completely wrong and I don't know why.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that I can think of is that the join is not one-to-one.  That is, there are mutliple rows in table2 that match each row in table1.  In this case, the results come from an arbitrary row.

Comment: Ok, that may be the problem. This project just got trickier. Going to wait till Monday to Accept.

Comment: Good call. @weewa Consider running a SELECT statement prior to running all updates.  You can put the SELECT * right before the FROM.  If the results don't look right, investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. A quick investigation revealed that my update query needs another `WHERE` statement or two, as your answer was true.